# How can I load a default image from a node field in page.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, media

I want to print the default image of a node field into the page.html.twig template file in Drupal 8. On doing my research the easiest approach I could find was

```
{% if node.field_image.entity %}
   <img src="{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}"
        alt="{{ node.field_image.alt  }}"
        {% if node.field_image.title %}
        title="{{ node.field_image.title }}"
        {% endif %}
   />
{% endif %}
```

This works if I load an image in the field but not otherwise with the default image of the image field. I want to use the above code to print the default image that I pick for this image field. Currently the above method gives `<img src="http://example.com/" alt="">` for the default image

How can I access the uri value of the default image in the src of the image tag above. Is there any other way to print the default image of a node in the page.htm.twig preferably from within the template layer as I don't have any experience with preprocess functions etc.? My objective is to have a static image which is the same throughout the content type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one approach, using a helper method. It assumes you have access to the loaded node entity ($entity), and would like to get either the set, or default image for a given image field. I've also left comments and links that explain why Drupal::service('entity.repository') is being used, and how I discovered the way in which the Image module loads the default image settings.

```
    /**
 * Get the set or default image uri for a file image field (if either
 * exist).
 * @param $entity
 * @param $fieldName
 * @return null|string
 */
function get_image_uri($entity, $fieldName) {
  $image_uri = NULL;
  if( $entity->hasField($fieldName) ) {
    try {
      $field = $entity->{$fieldName}; //Try loading from field values first.
      if ($field && $field->target_id) {
        $file = File::load($field->target_id);
        if ($file) {
          $image_uri = $file->getFileUri();
        }
      }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('get_image_uri')->notice($e->getMessage(), []);
    }

    // If a set value above wasn't found, try the default image.
    if (is_null($image_uri)) {
      try {
        $field = $entity->get($fieldName); // Loading from field definition
        if ($field) {
          // From the image module /core/modules/image/ImageFormatterBase.php
          // $default_image = $test->fieldDefinition->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getSetting('default_image');
          $default_image = $field->getSetting('default_image');
          if ($default_image && $default_image['uuid']) {
            // $defaultImageFile = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']));
            // See https://www.drupal.org/node/2549139  entityManager is deprecated.
            // Use entity.repository instead.
            $entityrepository = Drupal::service('entity.repository');
            $defaultImageFile = $entityrepository->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
            if($defaultImageFile) {
              $image_uri = $defaultImageFile->getFileUri();
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Drupal::logger('get_image_uri')->notice($e->getMessage(), []);
      }
    }
  }

  return $image_uri;
}
```

Comment: I get a `Error: Class 'File' not found in get_image_uri()` for when the field has a value and `$default_image['uuid']` is empty when I have a default image

Comment: `File::load` should be replace by `\Drupal\file\Entity\File::load`

Comment: Many thanks, it was really helpful. Regarding the `$file = File::load` stuff, you can remove many lines by just doing `$entity->{$fieldName}->entity->getFileUri();`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Blue Waters for the code snippet. I have used it in a preprocess function to integrate with the theme. Sharing my code here, so it helps someone else save some time.

I have a field names `field_images`, which I'm rendering in the template page.html.twig.
The default image properties uui, height & width are readily available in the field settings, so I thought adding the fileuri there would be the simplest approach.

My function in mytheme.theme

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (array_key_exists('node', $variables)) {
    $node = $variables['node'];

    if (isset($node) && !is_string($node)) {
      if ($node->hasField('field_images')) {
        $images = $node->get('field_images');

        if (sizeof($images) === 0) {
          $image = $images->getFieldDefinition();
          $defaultImage = $image->getSetting('default_image');

          $entityrepository = Drupal::service('entity.repository');
          $defaultImageFile = $entityrepository->loadEntityByUuid('file', $defaultImage['uuid']);

          if($defaultImageFile) {
            $defaultImageUri = $defaultImageFile->getFileUri();
            $defaultImage['fileuri'] = $defaultImageUri;
            $image->setSetting('default_image', $defaultImage);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in page.html.twig I have the following:

```
{% if node.field_images is not empty %}
  {% for image in node.field_images %}
    <img src="{{ file_url(image.entity.fileuri) }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" alt="{{ image.alt }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  {% set image = node.field_images.setting('default_image') %}
  <img src="{{ file_url(image.fileuri) }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" alt="{{ image.alt }}">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Worked around it by using static images instead of default images with the code `{{ base_path ~ directory }}` to get path to image (src) without any preprocessing.