# Defaut image value not showing up

Tags: 8, nodes, theming

In my article content type, I've added a header image (field_header_image) field which I placed a default image into it so that all articles would have a default image used if one wasn't needed. However, when creating an article and leaving that field as the default value, it doesn't actually use that default value. The page is created as if that value is empty.

Is there any way to make sure that this default value is used?

Is there a way to do this through the .theme file? Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: The solution to my problem was solved with the following solution: [Loading default image from a node field in page.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/261484/55607)

Answer (score 0):

If the default image was set correctly then the newly saved article nodes should pick it up. Check if the website's log show any related error messages.

If you want to go with another method then just:

1. Copy `node.tpl.php` in your website's themes folder to `node--article.tpl.php`;
2. Open `node--article.tpl.php` in editor and place the following code just before `print render($content);`:

`<img src="/path-to/image/image_file_name.ext">`

3. Save.
4. Clear your website's cache and revisit any article node.

Comment: I’m on a Drupal 8 website. I’ve done the above the D8 way and still the default image does not show up.

Comment: For Drupal 8 read https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions. So the copy should be called `node--type.html.twig`.

Comment: The default image was set correctly and there are no error messages. I've created a node--article.html.twig template already and have the content printing...the default image doesn't show up; hence my original question. Is there a way to set the default image through the .theme file?

Comment: Just creating the file is not enough to get to desired effect, you need to also add code in step #2: `<img src="/path-to/image/image_file_name.ext">`

Comment: I've done all of that already, still doesn't work. If I print `{{ content.field_header_image }}`, I get nothing. Even running `{{ kint(content.field_header_image) }}` comes back as null, even though I have a default image set in the content type.

Comment: @ACanadianCoder, because it's clear there is something wrong with your field image I advised you to use DIRECT link to the image instead. Can you just get your template output simple `test` word first as I have an impression now you might be working with a wrong template file.

Comment: I can’t use a direct link because I don’t actually want it to be displayed within that template file. I just need the field to hold a value so that I can use it within my page.html.twig file as I have it grabbing that field from various content types and using it as the background image for my page headers.

Comment: You have to separate two different issues: 1) get anything (take a `test` word, for example) displayed in your template file first - just to make sure you have created the correct template file; 2) and when you success step 1 start troubleshooting why the filed is not showing its content. What dpm() is giving for step 2?

Comment: 1.) the template file works for everything else. I already have it themed the way I want with no issues as all the other fields work as intended. 2.) I’ve already done the troubleshooting to the furthest extent as I could figure out. Nothing seems to be giving errors or issues. The default image just doesn’t hold a value, just null. That’s why I’m seeing if there’s a way to inject a default value through a preprocess function.

Comment: The default image won't be saved in each entries image field. It's just a replacement if there is no image loaded. So if you have a single default image for the content type, it is ok to use a direct link in if condition: `if (empty($image_field)) { print '<img src="some-path/image.ext">'; }`